# Pulling Change Request CSV from ServiceNow with specific columns (Fields) in Python

Tags: python, csv, servicenow

Currently I have

```
import requests
import json
import csv

# Set the request parameters
url= 'dev.service-now.com/change_request_list.do?CSV&'
user = 'myuser'
pwd = 'mypass'

# Set proper headers (Unsure if this is needed)
headers = {"Accept":"application/json"}

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers )
response.raise_for_status()


with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in response.iter_lines():
        writer.writerow(line.decode('utf-8').split(','))
```

This gets the data I want from ServiceNow however it is missing certain fields. I need the 'Opened' & 'Closed' Column and am unsure how to query that with the code I have.

Any help would be perfect! I am really new to using requests.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the Rest Table API that allows you to control what fields you want to pull. I also added a `sysparm_query` to restrict the rows.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = 'https://dev.service-now.com/api/now/table/change_request'
user = 'myuser'
pwd = 'mypass'

fields = ['number', 'short_description', 'opened_at', 'closed_at']
params = {
    'sysparm_display_value': 'true',
    'sysparm_exclude_reference_link': 'true',
    'sysparm_limit': '5000',
    'sysparm_fields': ','.join(fields),
    'sysparm_query': 'sys_created_on>2020-09-15'
}
headers = {"Accept":"application/json"}

response = requests.get(url + '?' + urlencode(params),
    auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)
response.raise_for_status()
rows = response.json()['result']

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    for row in rows:
        outputrow = []
        for field in fields:
                outputrow.append(row[field])
        writer.writerow(outputrow)
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, your code looks correct. I think you just need to update the web service URL you are using to provide the `sysparm_default_export_fields=all` parameter. I.E:
`dev.service-now.com/change_request_list.do?CSV&sysparm_default_export_fields=all`

After that, you should get a response containing every field, including system created fields like sys_id and created_on. Alternatively, you could create a new view in ServiceNow and provide the `sysparm_view=viewName` parameter in your URL.